# Dynamically compose DynamoDB Query Expression according to user input

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I'm writing an API endpoint to allow users to list items according to the parameters they pass in on the request body.

I want the partition key to be the only required parameter; clients will be allowed to pass zero or more key-value pairs to achieve the desired level of granularity in their query.

My DynamoDB Table holds items with the following structure:

```
{
  "appName": { //PARTITION KEY
    "S": "APP_1"
  },
  "requestId": { // SORT KEY
    "S": "request_1224"
  },
  "creationTime": {
    "N": "1636332520679"
  },
  "resolver": {
    "S": "SOMEONES_ID"
  },
  "status": {
     "S": "PENDING"
  }
}
```

I have some working code, where the `DynamoDBQueryExpression` is hard-coded and I do have an idea of how to dynamically put together the Query Expression but I'm thinking of an ugly combination of for-loops and string manipulation.

Is there an elegant and clean way of dynamically putting together the `DynamoDBQueryExpression`?

Here's the starter code I have, for reference:

```
    Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS(requestModel.getAppName()));
    eav.put(":val2", new AttributeValue().withS(accessRequestModel.getRequestStatus()));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<RequestModel> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<RequestModel>()
            .withKeyConditionExpression("appName = :val1")
            .withFilterExpression("RequestStatus = :val2")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
```

Just to be extra clear, see how I'm doing `put` and passing hard-coded values to `withFilterConditionExpression` –I'd like these values being passed dynamically according to client's input.

I'm using Java's [AWS DynamoDB Mapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.htmlhttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.htmlhttps://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html).